# Prononciation non claire : « triste et vieille <?> »

Tags: prononciation

Au point « [1866s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6HvksFXkTY&t=1866s) » de cette histoire on peut entendre « triste et vieille <?> ».
Est-ce que quelqu'un aurait une certitude quant à ce qui est dit?

Comment: Tes liens me donne: Video not available.

Comment: @Lambie Le lien fonctionne bien à partir de mon ordinateur (mais il est en France).

Comment: @Lambie Le film est géobloqué. Tu ne perds pas grand chose car [Urge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urge_(film)) n'est pas un chef d'œuvre et le fait qu'il soit en VF n'arrange rien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Plus tristes et vieilles que tes boules ?*

C'est à dire ici couilles, puisque c'est une réplique à :

> *J'ai acheté l'endroit pour ne pas tomber sur de vieilles couilles tristes.*

Note : Contrairement à ce qui est indiqué sur la vidéo postée sur YouTube, le titre original du film n'est pas "Destruction" mais *Urge* (en France "The Duke" et au Québec "Envie")

Comment: Ce n'est pas ce qu'on entend ; c'est « boules » ou « poules », mais alors ça n'a pas de sens.

Comment: Oui, boules, on lit *balls* sur les lèvres de l'actrice.

Comment: Serait-ce à dire qu'en français moderne on dit aussi « boules » pour « couilles »

Comment: Eh bien, oui, ça se dit : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/boule 1999

Comment: Bon, c'est du doublage mais bien sûr, *boules* peut avoir ce sens. https://jaimelesmots.com/x-facons-de-dire-les-testicules/#:~:text=Comme%20pour%20tout%20ce%20qui,%22les%20grelots%22%2C%20%22les

Comment: Oui d'autant que la réplique précédente est "j'ai acheté l'endroit pour ne pas tomber sur de vieilles couilles tristes".

Answer (score 0):

Oui c’est ça. « Plus triste et vieille que tes poules ? »

Comment: Ça me semble bizarre ; je crois entendre « que tes boules ». Il n'est pas inutile d'écouter la partie juste avant ; on trouve dans celle-ci « vieilles couilles tristes », et en anglais le mot « couilles » c'est « balls », ce qui donne « boules », mais on n'utilise pas cette traduction littérale en français ; tout cela fait que je ne suis pas sûr de ce qui est dit, que ce soit du point de vue prononciation ou sens.